# Execute javascript synchronously in Jupyter Notebook cell

Tags: javascript, python, jupyter-notebook, vis.js

In a Jupyter Notebook, we can execute Javascript/HTML cells directly to enrich the Notebook display, e.g. an interactive `Vis.js` graph, thanks to the following `import`:

```
from IPython.display import Javascript
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
```

I have the following Notebook cells:

- Cell 1: Register an utility function so that later it can be called multiple times.

```
%%javascript
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        vis: 'vis'
    }
});

require(['vis'], function(vis){
    function drawNetworkGraph() {
    ...
    }
    window.drawNetworkGraph = drawNetworkGraph;
});
```

- Cell 2: Try invoking the utility function.

```
transfer_data_from_python_to_javascript = "..."
display(Javascript(transfer_data_from_python_to_javascript))
display(Javascript("""window.drawNetworkGraph();""")) // <-- problem here!
```

When executing "Run All" in the Notebook, I got a Race Condition where `window.drawNetworkGraph is not a function` in DevTools Console.

This is due to `require(, function(){})` in Cell 1 ran asynchronously. It takes some time for the browser to load the `vis` library; and when it is finished loading, it will invoke the function declared in the 2nd argument of `require()`. At this point of time, the Jupyter Notebook already executes the Cell 2, leading to `not a function`.

#### Question

In Javascript world, it's highly recommended to write code in asynchronous manner. That's why `require()` supports callback. *What is the best practice to overcome such setup in Jupyter Notebook?*

My goal is to embed `vis.js` graph. Feel free to suggest anything. Thank you.

#### My attempts

1). Remove Cell 1. In Cell 2 or similar Cell, whenever wanting to invoke such utility function, we enclose all javascript in Cell 1. Downside: cumbersome because we have many other latter cells which invoke the utility function.

2). Use "wait for" mechanism in javascript: check if `window.drawGraphNetwork` is defined or not; if available, call it; if not, `setTimeOut` to call it a little bit later. Downside: a little bit more complicated.

Nevertheless, these approaches are less elegant.